# Why I cannot format string in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Here is a string `template` read from file.

```
Name: %s
Age: %d
```

After I read it from file, I want to format this string using given name and age.

```
var template = File("file_path").readText()

MessageFormat.format(template, "Bod", 123)

print(template)
```

However I cannot format `template`. Its output is.

```
Name: %s
Age: %d
```

Comment: True, I removed the flag

Comment: You mixed `MessageFormat` and `String` formatting. `String.format` use `%s` where `MessageFormat` use `{0}`

Comment: @AxelH Yes you are right. Thanks a lot.

Comment: 你这样整是不行的，要传一个数组的话建议你使用我之前给的那种直接把数组放在第二个参数的做法(`String.format("%s", *array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either use `String.format` instead of `MessageFormat.format` or use `{0}`/`{1}` instead of `%s`/`%d`.

Comment: If i want to put an array, what can I do?

Comment: Just pass individual array elements.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Do I have to put array elements one by one? Can I directly pass array?

Comment: @CoXier if the array contains _all_ of your arguments you can pass it as a `vararg` parameter using the `*` operator (`*array`), this is the Kotlin equivalent of passing a `T[]` to a `T...` in Java